# How to remove a field from a List of Object using java 8, below is the example of what I want to achieve

Tags: java, jpa

I have an Entity class as Category (below is sample)

```
@Entity
class Category {
private int id;
private String name;
private String address;
private Date createDate;
private Date modifiedDate;
}
```

I am using `JPA`, and when I am doing

```
findAll(); // JPA repository
```

I am getting createdDate and modifiedDate as well, But I don't want to fetch them.

So Is there a way to filter the fetched list by removing the createDate and modifiedDate fields. ?

Comment: I would say that it is not really "JPA", but you could use a JPA query or try FetchGroup if your JPA implementation allows it (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_fetchgroup.htm)

Comment: You can use `@Query` for the same

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
class Category {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private Date createDate;
   private Date modifiedDate;

   Category(){
   }

   // This constructor will be used to fetch only desired columns
   Category(String id, String name, String address){
        this.id =  id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
   }
}
```

In your `repository` you need to define the `@Query` as

```
@Query("SELECT new com.test.Category(cat.id, cat.name, cat.address) FROM Category cat")
List<Category> findAll();
```

**Note:** You need to replace `com.test.Category` to your actual package for `Category`